# Can PLY process input without loading it all into memory?

Tags: python, ply

I'd like to use Python's [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply) to analyze a huge portion of text, that could reach 1GB in size.

Is it possible to have PLY read the text and parse it as a stream, so I wouldn't have to load the whole thing into memory? I want to go over the text line-by-line, and have PLY analyze it. Is that possible?

Comment: Could you read it line by line using normal IO and pass each line to PLY?

Comment: What kind of text is it? More details are always useful.

Comment: Gcode for 3d printer. Can't read line by line because my patterns are multiline. So I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like PLY uses Python's `re` module which can't handle a stream, therefore it can't handle a stream as well.

Comment: Though I wonder whether passing an `mmap` object to PLY is going to work.